# New-PSSession in an Azure-runbook (ARM)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

For an Azure VM in the classic portal (ASM) I was able to obtain

1. the required credentials with `Get-AutomationPSCredential` and
2. the `-ConnectionURI` with [`Connect-AzureVM.ps1`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-to-an-Azure-85f0782c).

With these two parameters I was able to successfully execute a `New-PSSession` in an Azure-runbook.

**Q** What am I supposed to do to open a PS-Session in an Azure-runbook to an Azure-VM (ARM)?

**Update**

command in runbook (ARM)

`$vmSession = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'https://xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com:5985' -Credential $creds -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)`

error-message

> New-PSSession : [xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com] Connecting to
>   remote server xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com
>   failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the
>   operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the
>   computer is accessible over the network, and  that a firewall
>   exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this
>   computer. By default, the WinRM  firewall exception for public
>   profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
>   subnet. For more  information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
>   Help topic.

Comment: you've already asked a question about it, why do you ask again?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Even if I do have the -ConnectionURI which I've asked for, I'm not able to execute New-PSSession because of tons of errors :(

Comment: well, post the errors at least?? post your code

Comment: @4c74356b41 ok, I've added an update.

Comment: did you open the port on the NSG? can you manually connect? not from a runbook?

Comment: psremoting enabled on target-machine ?

Comment: yes, I'm able to open a remote desktop.

Comment: what does RDP has to do with pssession?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry, got you wrong concerning rdp. I added a rule to the NSG. Restarted the AzureVM and executed `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`. Fired up another AzureVM. Both tests neither AzureVM nor locally succeeded Test-WSMan -Computername xxx.

Comment: from one vm to another? in the same vnet? that's impossible unless you set nsg rules at the adapter level

Comment: @4c74356b41 the vms are on different vnets.

Comment: well, something is wrong with your nsg\firewall rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your error, it seems that the port 5985 is blocked by some firewalls. You could use `telnet` to test connectivity.

```
telnet xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com 5985
```

If it fails, you should check additionally:

1. Open port 5985 on Windows Firewall(Inbound rules).
2. Open port 5985 on Azure NSG(Inbound rules). Pay attention to NSG could be associated to NIC or subnet, you had better check them all.

[image]

3. On your server VM, execute cmdlet.

   winrm quickconfig

Ensure you can access port 5985, then test on your local PC, and then test on an Azure Runbook.

I use the following cmdlets, it works for me.

```
New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://IP:5985' -Credential $creds -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

Notes: If you don't configure a certificate on your server, you can not use `https` and you should use `http` instead.

```
PS C:\Users\v-shshui> New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://*.*.*.*:5985' -Credential $creds -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)

 Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  7 Session7        *.*.*.*         RemoteMachine   Opened        Microsoft.PowerShell     Available
```

Also, if you want to use `https`, you need to configure a certificate as in shown in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019527/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https).

**Update**

If you want to `winrm` to your VM in an Azure Runbook, you should use `https`. It means that you should open port 5986 (by default) on Azure NSG and Windows Firewall. Also, you need add a new certificate on the Azure VM.

Comment: I'm almost there. `Test-WSman` is now working from everywhere (localhost, runbook, other AzureVM). But, `New-PSSession` is reporting the following error "The server certificate 
on the destination computer (xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com:5985) has the following errors:
Encountered an internal error in the SSL library. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
"

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work either: _The WinRM client 
cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not 
joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts 
configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not 
be authenticated._

Comment: I need to execute the `New-PSSession` from a Azure runbook.

Comment: @participant By default `http` use port 5985, `https` use port 5986. So, if you want to use `https`, you should open port 5986 on Azure NSG and firewall. How to configure `https`, you could check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019527/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142891/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-participant).

Comment: @participant You don't need buy a certificate, you could use  self signed certificate. You could check this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/). I test on runbook, it works for me. You also could check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724096/azure-powershell-how-to-get-running-services-of-a-vm-via-runbook/43731079#43731079) about this.

Comment: @participant Do you join your VM in a domain? Do you try `admin` not `local\host`? I test in my lab, my VM is not in a domain. I only use `admin` as the user. It works for me.