# New-PSSession in an Azure-runbook: Access denied (ARM)

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

With the advice provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658413/new-pssession-in-an-azure-runbook-arm) I was able to set up the `winrm` on a Azure VM(1).

Right now, I can open a PS-Session with `New-PSSession` from

- any Azure VM(2) to the Azure VM(1)
- my local machine which to the Azure VM(1)

But if I do exactly the same within an Azure runbook,

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "admin"
InlineScript
{
   $vmSession = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'https://xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com:5986' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
}
```

it fails with the error message:

*New-PSSession : [xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com] Connecting to remote server 
xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied.*

As user I use `localhost\admin" and I'm positiv, the password is correct (double-checked it).

**Q** How can I overcome the *Access denied*?

**Update**

PS-workflow got the best of me. So, there is only a minor syntactical problem in the code above. If somebody shares the right answer I'm happy to up-vote and accept it.

Comment: $cred could not be used in your script? `{ Write-Output "password $cred";
   $vmSession = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'https://xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com:5986' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
}`

Comment: Could you print `$cred` in your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [official documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/PSWorkflow/about/about_InlineScript?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> By default, the variables that are defined in a workflow are not
>   visible to the commands in the InlineScript script block. To make
>   workflow variables visible to the InlineScript, use the $Using scope
>   modifier. The $Using scope modifier is required only once for each
>   variable in the InlineScript.

So, you need modify your script as below:

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "admin"
InlineScript
{
   $vmSession = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'https://xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com:5986' -Credential $Using:cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
}
```

Comment: The first version is not working. I think you can't call `Get-AutomationPSCredential` from within an `InlineScript`-block.