# Azure Automation RunBook Download File from Blob To VM

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

Is there a way to use Azure Automation to download a file from azure storage? I can currently connect to the VM using templates from the gallery to create files/folder but how would I download a file from storage?

I am currently trying to use Get-AzureStorageBlob command from Invoke-command -ScriptBlock

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the powershell cmdlets, you need to remember to login to Azure prior to executing them.  See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-runas-account).  You would need to login in on the remote computer (ie: inside the Script Block).

An alternative is to have azcopy accessible, and simply pass in the key information via Automation Credentials.

Comment: I am able to perform file creation inside the Script block using basic PS commands. Ex. New-Item. I will try using AzCopy but probably need to install it via DSC first. Thanks for your recommendation I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, based on my experience, you need do the following steps.

1.Install Azure PowerShell on your target VM.

2.Enable Winrm on your VM, you need open port 5986 on Windows Firewall and Azure NSG. You also need configuration certificate on your VM. You could check this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/) that step by step to enable winrm on Azure VM.

Note: You should enable winrm listening on https, if you enable it on http, you could not winrm your VM on runbook script.

3.Login to your Azure subscription in runbook, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual#step-5---add-authentication-to-manage-azure-resources) about this.

4.Use `New-PSSession` to login your VM in runbook and execute your PowerShell cmlet. You could check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756823/new-pssession-in-an-azure-runbook-access-denied-arm) about this.

Comment: Ill try initiating a new PS Session and running the command from there. Azure PS Module is installed on the target machine. The blob is around 15GB being downloaded to target VM.

Comment: @DXH Why you don't download the blob on your target VM? Do you need automation download the blob every day or every month?

Comment: This solution is needed because we have a client that is disconnected from our cloud vnet. A database refresh is done everyday. Currently I used PS scripts that is ran locally on the VM using Task Scheduler. Maybe I can use Azure Automation to launch that PS script that is stored locally but I am trying to centralize all my scripts so that it wont be a nightmare managing it on multiple servers. Also, credentials is an issue. Every time a password is change i have to update on each server, I can bypass this by using the storage account keys but it is exposed.

Comment: @DXH Yes, you could use automation account to execute your local PowerShell script. What you should do is you need runbook to login your VM, but if your VM's credentials changes, if possible, you could create a account that use runbook to execute your local script. If you only want to winrm your VM, you don't need to login your Azure subscription.